# Proof that if $p^r$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ then $p^r\le2n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Let $p$ be a prime and let $n$ be a positive integer. Then $p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ exactly $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log_p 2n\rfloor} \left\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^i}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$ times. This follows from $v_p(n!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log_p n \rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$, where $v_p(n)$ is the largest power of $p$ that exactly divides $n$, and $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$. So, why then does $p^r\vert\binom{2n}{n}$ imply that $p^r\leq2n$?.

Edit: Thank you to @BrunoB. I see why now.
From the definition of the greatest integer function you have $$\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^i}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor\leq\frac{2n-n}{p^i}=\frac{n}{p^i}\lt \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor+1$$
$$\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^i}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor\lt\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor+1 $$
$$\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^i}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor\lt1 $$

Since every term in the summation is less than 1, and there are at most $\left\lfloor\log_p2n\right\rfloor$ terms, you have
$$v_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)\lt\left\lfloor\log_p2n\right\rfloor\leq\log_p2n$$
$$p^{v_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)}\leq 2n$$

Since $p^r\vert\binom{2n}{n}$, $r$ cannot exceed $v_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)$. Thus,
$$p^r \leq p^{v_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)}\leq 2n$$
$$p^r\leq 2n$$ $\square$

Comment: Hint for your situation: try to prove that each difference in your first sum is less than $1$.

Comment: @BrunoB That seems to work, thank you

Comment: Why are people voting to reopen? It is still a duplicate.